# unable to get an account BIS

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, registration

When I want to get an account BIS, a window popup appear like in the picture.
And to make the steps cited in the popup: option > theDevice > Advanced System Settings > Host Routing Table. Then I Pressed the Menu key and clicked Register Now. I obtain Registration message queued. It will be sent once data coverage is available.

[image]

Comment: OFF TOPIC: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"

Answer (score 0):

You could try a battery pull reboot and see if it fixes it. If not try resending the service books .It sends the service books for the BlackBerry Internet Service. you can look [here](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB02830) to get information about how to do it.

Comment: Can you verify the link [here][1]. I can't access.